Inconsistent Results Between Pandas and Polars using cut (and qcut)?
I'm trying to switch from Pandas to Polars to create quantile-based portfolios. The goal is to categorize a numerical variable into equal-sized portfolios using quantile breakpoints. However, I'm noticing that the bins generated by Pandas and Polars are not the same, leading to inconsistent results between the two implementations.
Any ideas how to get the same results between Pandas and Polars??
Function for quantile-based binning using Pandas
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

def nqtile(df, sorting_variable, nq):
    # Calculate quantile breakpoints
    breakpoints = np.quantile(
        df[sorting_variable].dropna(), 
        np.linspace(0, 1, nq + 1), 
        method="linear"
    )
    
    # Assign observations to bins
    nqports = pd.cut(
        df[sorting_variable],
        bins=nq,
        labels=range(1, breakpoints.size),
        include_lowest=True,
        right=False
    )
    
    return nqports

Function for quantile-based binning using Polars
def nqtile_pl(df, sorting_variable, nq):
    # Calculate quantile breakpoints
    breakpoints = np.quantile(
        df[sorting_variable].drop_nulls(), 
        np.linspace(0, 1, nq + 1), 
        method="linear"
    )
    
    # Remove the first and last breakpoints for binning
    breakpoints_1 = breakpoints[1:-1]
    labels_list = [str(i) for i in range(1, nq + 1)]
    
    # Assign observations to bins
    nqports = pl.Series.cut(
        df[sorting_variable],
        breaks=breakpoints_1,
        labels=labels_list,
        left_closed=False
    )
    return nqports

Example
data = {
    'id': np.random.choice(range(1, 20), size=1000, replace=True),
    'random_number': np.random.randint(1, 100, size=1000)
}

# Create a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Apply Pandas-based quantile binning
df['port_Q_pd'] = nqtile(df, 'random_number', 5)
df['port_Q_pd'] = df['port_Q_pd'].astype(int)

# Convert to Polars DataFrame
df_pl = pl.DataFrame(df)

# Apply Polars-based quantile binning and add to the DataFrame
df_pl = df_pl.with_columns(
    nqtile_pl(df_pl, 'random_number', 5).alias('port_Q_pl')
)

# Convert back to Pandas for comparison
df_conf = df_pl.to_pandas()

# Ensure both columns are integers for comparison
df_conf['port_Q_pl'] = df_conf['port_Q_pl'].astype(int)
df_conf['port_Q_pd'] = df_conf['port_Q_pd'].astype(int)

# Calculate the confusion matrix to compare the results
cm = confusion_matrix(df_conf['port_Q_pl'], df_conf['port_Q_pd'])



[[207   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 200   0   0   0]
 [  0   0 183  13   0]
 [  0   0   0 184  19]
 [  0   0   0   0 194]]

